# How can I update an value in a variable in Python?

Tags: python

I'm hoping to make a variable that changes when a value "in it" changes. That may sound confusing.

I'm new to Python, and I'm hoping to use this in future projects.

Here's an explanation. Say I have the variable *foo* and I want it to always be equal to *bar* plus three.

If I do

```
bar = 6
foo = bar+3
```

Then *foo* is equal to 9. But if I then do

```
bar = 5
```

Then foo is still 9. I'd like foo to be equal to 8, without executing

```
foo = bar+3
```

again. Is there anything I can do to make that happen?

Thanks.

EDIT: Thanks for the answers! I was already aware about how variables work. I guess using functions with `return` is the only way to do it.

Comment: It's not possible to `+ 3` *without executing* `+ 3`. You can hide it behind a class (look up object-oriented programming), but you will still be executing the same logic.

Comment: That sounds more like a function.

Comment: If you think the answers answer your question, please consider accepting the one that you think is the best by clicking on that checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

`foo` can be defined like this:

```
foo = lambda: bar + 3
```

And can be used like this:

```
print(foo())
```

As you can see, `foo` is no longer a variable. `foo` is a function. `foo` can't be a variable because a variable doesn't suddenly change its value just because some other variable's value changed.

Answer (score 1):

When you type

```
foo = bar + 3
```

It does not mean "`foo` is equal to three more than the value of `bar`", it means "`foo` is equal to three more than the value of `bar` *RIGHT NOW*."

If you need to do the former, you'll need to do some trickery.

```
class DelayedAdditionContext(object):
    def __init__(self, bar=0):
        self.bar = bar

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self.bar + 3

context = DelayedAdditionContext()
context.bar = 5
context.foo  # 8
context.bar = 8
context.foo  # 11
```

but really this is just making a function under the hood.

```
def calculate_foo(bar):
    return bar + 3

bar = 5
foo = calculate_foo(bar)  # 8

bar = 8
foo = calculate_foo(bar)  # 11
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use an object-oriented method to define Bar and Foo in the same class. If you want to get the value of foo, call the method in the class to perform foo = bar+3. I don't know if I can help you. I am a rookie.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you're uncertain of the quality of your answer or your ability to respond in a worthwhile way, please refrain from responding. After you earn 50 points reputation, [consider writing a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) in response to the question.